# Export an object to be reused in another JavaScript file without the default operator

Tags: javascript, object, export

I have two files in a tree that defines an object.

The `common.js` file.

```js
export default {
  table: {
    actions: {
      save:   'Save',
      delete: 'Delete',
      update: 'Update'
    }
  }
};
```

In another file, I am calling the `common.js` file I just stated.

```js
var common = require('common.js');
```

And whenever I access the object, as said, I get this;

```js
console.log(common);
```

```
{
  common:{
    default: {
      table: {
        actions: {
          save: 'Save',
          delete: 'Delete',
          update: 'Update'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm looking forward to get is the following;

```
{
  common: {
    table: {
      actions: {
        save:   'Save',
        delete: 'Delete',
        update: 'Update'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is without the `default` key. Is there a way I can export the table object and get it without the default key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `import` syntax instead of `require` syntax, and the value of the import will be the default export:

```
import common from 'common.js';
const obj = {
  common,
  // ...
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/5350980o54